# Passing absolute paths to subprocess.call() [Python]

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm working on a script that should call an external executable file, which takes a path as an argument(and generates another file). I used the following syntax:
`call(['C:/program.exe', 'C:/input.txt'])`
It should generate an output.txt in the same directory.
My problem is that I don't get any output, or error message. If I run that command manually in cmd, everything works fine.
How can I solve this?

Comment: In which directory is Python executing when you run this command? Does *that* directory contain the expected output file?

Comment: @tripleee @seenorth The Python script is located in a different directory, but that shouldn't matter as long as I use the absolute path of my executable and input file. I can run the same command `C:/program.exe C:/input.txt` in cmd(regardless of the current working directory), and the output file is generated in the same directory where my executable is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Popen to get an error message.

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen
Popen(['C:/program.exe', 'C:/input.txt'], stdout=PIPE)
for line in process.stdout:
    print(line)
```

I also suspect that your executable isn't working, because the working directory is different.